# Xamarin forms UI design Ipad and Iphone Size

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to develop an application in Xamarin forms that its UI will work for both an Iphone screen size and an Ipad screen size?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Xamarin provide automatic resize app for all resolution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 
I used OnIdiom to adopt phone and tablet size